# Python pyramid encrypted session recommendation

Tags: python, session, web, pyramid

Looking at the documentation for pyramid session the default session says - Session data is unencrypted (but it is signed / authenticated).

I looked at beaker but this doesn't seem to have the documentation page up anymore at http://beaker.groovie.org/

What *current* alternatives are there for an encrypted session ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the github project is *active* - https://github.com/bbangert/beaker - I guess just the pypi docs point to an old site.

Comment: PyPI is updated only when a release is cut. The most current version is always in the code repo. I submitted a PR to update all the links in the README.rst, which should be corrected in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-nacl-session/en/latest/ which is an official addon for handling encrypted sessions. Beaker is also great and you can use that too.